# How to obtain output in a text file on Linux machine for commands executed on remote host over SSH?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, shell-script, bash-scripting

How to obtain output in a text file on Linux machine locally for commands executed on remote host over SSH ?

- For example I SSH a remote host: `ssh admin@10.0.0.1`
- Provide Password: `admin@IP 10.0.0.1's password: xxxx`
- Now I give command to get the logs: `show eventlog`

Now I want to capture and save the output of this command in a text file and store that file on my local Linux machine manually or through a script.
Also if I want to get the output from multiple devices what should be the process ?

Answer (score 0):

For redirecting the remote output to a single file

```
ssh user@ssh-server.com '(script or command)' > ./local_filename
```

For multiple files loop through a list of servers and logins. If they have a common Kerberos ticket or a similar auth the process would be more simple. And append a counter to the filename `./local_filename_count`

For more details: https://linuxconfig.org/executing-commands-remotely-with-ssh-and-output-redirection

Comment: Can we also put a wait timer to run our command after login on remote device so that it waits for a particular period before executing the command after SSH login ?

Comment: Yes, `sleep` command works. Try `script_A && sleep {1/1m/2h/3d} && script_B`